# MapRoute gives 404 error when controller is located in a subfolder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5.1

Trying to add an MVC route to my project to handle a subfolder with controllers. My project structure is as follows:

/Controllers/

- HomeController
- SomeOtherController

/Controllers/Admin

- AdminController
- SomeController

/Views

- Home
- SomeOther

/Views/Admin

- Admin
- Some

The issue is that the controller/views in the admin folders are not being found and giving a n HTTP404 error.

Here is my `RouteConfig`

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Admin",
        url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I understand that I could use Areas, but I don't want to create a new MVC structure. I simply want to organize my controllers and views into an admin folder.

Comment: Could you try putting this route before the default, I know it sounds odd but thats just how i've always done it?

Comment: Whoa, that worked! Why did it work? am I missing something or should it not matter the order? Anyways, post it as an answer so I can give you the credit. Thanks!

Comment: Add as the answer, I honestly have no idea. Was just how I was taught to do it and have blindly followed. I will do some research and try to pad the answer out a bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try putting this new route before the default.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Admin",
    url: "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

[The importance of route order](http://www.freddes.se/2009/12/09/the-importance-of-the-order-of-routes-in-asp-net-mvc/).

It worked because routes are evaluated from top to bottom, as `name: "Default"`, was at top it was handing every thing – [Satpal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1668533)

Comment: It worked because routes are evaluated from top to bottom, as `name: "Default",` was at top it was handing every thing